# how can i make a write function that not in the main

Tags: java

I have a code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Tutorial6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       int choose;
       System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
       choose = scanner.nextInt();
       if(choose == '1'){
          write();
}
       else{
          read();
}
    }

    public static void write() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
       PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("users.txt", true));
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       String name, address, ages;
       System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
       name = scanner.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Enter your address: ");
       address = scanner.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Enter your ages: ");
       ages = scanner.nextLine();

       output.println(name + " " + address + " " + ages + "\n");

       output.flush();
       output.close();

    }
    
        public static void read(){
       Scanner input = new Scanner (new File("users.txt"));
       while (input.hasNext())  {
           System.out.println(input.nextLine());
       }
       input.close();
    }
}
```

it have an error called Unhandled exception type. How can I fix it, I have tried to put the write and read function in different java class and it work fine. But I want it to work like a register text interface app.

Comment: in which line you have *Unhandled exception type.*

Comment: You either need to throw the same exceptions from the main class as the writer class, or you need to deal with the Exceptions somewhere (Put `write();` inside a try/catch block for example). Do one or the other, but they don't just magically go away when you throw them.

Comment: Add the exception to your method signature's `throws` section.

Answer (score 1):

Surround `write` function call with `try-catch` block

```
if(choose == '1'){
    try{
        write();
    } catch(Exception e){
        // handle exception here
    }
} else {
    read();
}
```

Comment: thank you and what do you mean by handle exception (sorry i'm new to this stuff)

Comment: means what to do (handle exception) when an exception is encountered in your case you have to handle 2 exceptions `IOException` and `ClassNotFoundException`.